# Ignore all matches to negated extglob pattern in recursive ls

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ls

I would like to recursively list all files in a directory which match a given input pattern **using ls**. (Oh, and this is in Bash).

The only way I can think of to do this using ls is to `shopt -s extglob` and then use the `ls --ignore=pattern` option with the extended glob negate pattern `!( pattern-list )`. Seems kind of roundabout to negate in an ignore but otherwise wildcards don't recurse.

Assuming I already have the directory to look in as `dir` and the pattern to match against as `file`, this is my current attempt:

`ls -AR --ignore='!('"${file}"')' ${dir}`

However, this does not seem to have the desired effect, for example in a test case where the directory structure gives this output for `ls -AR`:

```
    .:
    a  a.c  b  b.c  c  c.h  s

    ./s:
    a  a.c  b  b.c  c  c.h
```

My command with `file = *.c` and `dir = s` (full command: `ls -AR --ignore=!(*.c) s`) gives this output:

```
    ./s:
    a  a.c  b  b.c  c  c.h
```

I know I could pipe it into grep quite easily, and do something like `ls -AR s | grep -v '.*.c'` and get output like:

```
    s:
    a
    b
    c
    c.h
```

but I am looking for a way to do this just through `ls`.

Sorry if I was unclear at all, this is my first time on a StackExchange site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding the `globstar` shell option and the `-d` flag to `ls` to not automatically list directory contents?

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s globstar
ls -d  **/!(*.c)
```

Comment: Great suggestion, I didn't know they added globstar. However, since I am looking to match the input pattern (which wasn't clear, fixed that), not omit it I think I need to use `ls -dAR **/*.c`.

Comment: Note that contrary to `zsh` (where that feature originated) and `ksh93` (where `bash` copied it from), `bash`'s `**` follows symbolic links when descending the directory tree, which can have serious unwanted effects. So use with care or use `find` or other shells if there's a risk that there be symlinks in the directory.

Comment: @choroba, the `-A` and `-R` options don't make sense in combination with `-d` and can be removed (the shell makes up the list of files here, not `ls`, `ls` in that case is just outputting the list so could be replaced with `printf '%s\n'`). Also, you need `--` to mark the end of options or write it `ls -dAR ./**/!(*.c)` to avoid problems with filenames starting with `-`. Also, if there's no c file and if there's a directory called `**` and a file called `!(*.c)` inside it, `ls` will report it even though it's not a `c` file. You may want to add the `failglob` option.

Comment: The symlink issue has now been fixed in `bash-4.3`

Answer (score 2):

GNU `ls` `--ignore` option takes standard file name patterns, not a `ksh` extended one (what `bash` (and `bash` only, not `ls`) recognises with `extglob`)

So you can do:

```
ls -AR --ignore='*.[ch]' --ignore='*.cpp'
```

But you can't do:

```
ls -AR --ignore='!(*.[ch]|*.cpp)'
```

Which would just ignore files named like: `!(foo.c|bar.cpp)`.

In `ls -AR --ignore=!(*.c)`, since the pattern is not quoted, `bash` would try to expand it before passing it to `ls`. So it would look in the current directory for files whose name starts with `"--ignore="` and doesn't end in `".c"`. For instance, if there were two files, one called `--ignore=foo` and one called `--ignore=bar`, it would run `ls` with those four arguments: `"ls"`, `"-AR"`, `"--ignore=bar"`, `"--ignore=foo"`.

You can do (with GNU find).

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.([ch]|cpp)' -ls
```

Or with any POSIX `find`:

```
find . \( -name '*.[ch]' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Or assuming there's no symlinks to directories:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar dotglob failglob
ls -ld -- **/*.@([ch]|cpp)
```

This time, `bash` does expand the globbing pattern and passes the list of files to `ls`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, that explains `extglob` nicely.